# How to disable Turbolinks in a specific page other than using body tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, turbolinks

```
%div.col-md-2
  Last updated (h:m):
  %div
    %body{"data-turbolinks" => "false"}
      %strong= current_user.last_active_at ? local_time(current_user.last_active_at, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M') : 'N/A'
```

Turbolinks is disabled when using "data-turbolinks" => "false" in the body tag and works fine but we  cannot use body tag somewhere middle of the code, so trying it in any other tag like div does not work in disabling the turbolinks ,so is there any way of doing it without using body tag ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

In your `app/helpers/application_helper.rb` file, create a blacklist turbolinks array which will have all the pages on which turbolinks needs to be disabled in the format `controller/action`. Say you don't want turbolinks in `welcome controller's index action, articles controller's show action`:

```rb
# app/helpers/application_helper.rb

module ApplicationHelper

  def turbolinks_blacklist_array
    ["welcome/index", "articles/show"]
  end
end
```

Then in your `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`:

```
  <body
    <% if turbolinks_blacklist_array.include?("#{params[:controller]}/#{params[:action]}") %>
      <%= 'data-turbolinks="false"'.html_safe %>
    <% end %>
  >
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
```

EDIT: Or use a onelines:

```
<body <%= turbolinks_blacklist_array.include?("#{params[:controller]}/#{params[:action]}") ? 'data-turbolinks="false"'.html_safe : '' %>>


</body>
```

Comment: I've used `erb` format, but I think the same can be translated to `haml`. I never used haml.

Comment: Is there any way that we can achieve it other than using the `body` tag?

Comment: @user11350468 If you're looking to disable turbolinks on whole page then I think this is the best method. But I think you can also disable them on links. Ex: `<%= link_to 'Show', article, data: { turbolinks: false } %>`